# Show which of the following norms are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

On the vector space $C^1[0,1]$ of all real valued continuously differentiable functions defined in $[0,1]$, consider the following norms :

$\displaystyle ||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{0\le x\le 1}f(x)$ ,

$\displaystyle ||f||_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx$ ,

$\displaystyle ||f||_2=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$ ,

$\displaystyle ||f||_3=\max\{||f||_{\infty},||f'||_{\infty}\}$. Then which are correct ?

(A) $||f||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_2$ are equivalent.

(B) $||f||_1$ and $||f||_2$ are equivalent.

(C) $||f||_1$ and $||f||_3$ are equivalent.

(D) $||f||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_3$ are equivalent.

(E) $||f||_2$ and $||f||_3$ are equivalent.

**My Try :**

I found that $||f||_1 \le ||f||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_{\infty}\le ||f||_2$. But I am unable to find the converses. $||f'||_{\infty}$ creates my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try doesn't seem to take you anywhere. What you would like to show is that $||f||_2\le||f||_\infty\le C||f||_2$ or similar. Note that there is no question about $||f||_1$ vs $||f||_\infty$.

What you also would aim at is to make a good "guess" on whether two norms are equivalent or not in order to known if to prove or disprove it.

For example (A) is false because $||f'||_\infty$ can become arbitraliy large without affecting $||f||_\infty$. Take for examlple $f(x) = \sin\omega x$. This means that there is no $C$ such that $||f||_2 \le C ||f||_\infty$.

Similar construct can be used to disprove (B), (C) and (D).

For (E) on the other hand looks correct. On one hand you have that either $||f||_\infty$ or $||f'||_\infty$ is equal to $||f||_3$ (and the other non-negative) making $||f||_2\ge||f||_3$. On the other hand both $||f||_\infty$ and $||f'||_\infty$ are no larger than $||f||_3$ so you have:

$$||f||_2 = ||f||_\infty + ||f'||_\infty \le ||f||_3 + ||f||_3 = 2 ||f||_3 \le 2||f||_2$$